# Guidelines to install Kubernetes with IPv6 only

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6

I am trying to install **kubernetes on Bare Metal with IPv6 only networks**. I have stuck saying that **Invalid Arguments** whenever I put IPv6 address instead of IPv4 address.

---

Can anyone suggest any guidelines how to install Kubernetes on IPv6 only networks.
I know, it's not IPv6 production ready but in the source code, it seems,few component does have support for IPv6 -- that's why I am trying.

Comment: Hire some developers to add IPv6 support to Kubernetes.

Comment: @Ista Ranjan Samanta :  Have you found solution for this problem ? Can you share the steps that involved ?

Answer (score 3):

IPv6 is not supported at this time, and it's very clearly state in the docs that it's a work in progress: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/networking.md

Comment: We are burning out of addresses. Could you please suggest any idea regarding that. Our scale would be approximately millions/sec/tenant.  At least any other Container Orchestration System that can solve our problem.

Comment: I believe Apache Mesos support IPv6 (not 100% sure) but I think that warrants a completely different question.

Answer (score 3):

8v you can take Kubernetes IPv6 for a test drive

https://github.com/leblancd/kube-v6

There have been many recent changes that have been added or proposed to Kubernetes for supporting IPv6 are either not merged yet, or they were merged after the latest official release of Kubernetesi (1.8.0). In the meantime, we need a way of exercising these yet "in-flight" IPv6 changes on a Kubernetes cluster. This wiki offers you two ways to include these changes in a Kubernetes cluster instance:

Using "canned" (precompiled/prebuilt) release binaries and container images for Kubernetes components (e.g. https://github.com/leblancd/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.9.0-alpha.0.ipv6.0)
Compiling your own Kubernetes binaries and container images.

Answer (score -1):

## 2023 - up to date answer

Nowadays you can create a Kubernetes cluster entirely based on IPv6, and it won't be any more difficult than making it IPv4 ready.

If you follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ferdinandklr/creating-a-production-ready-self-hosted-kubernetes-cluster-from-scratch-on-a-vps-ipv6-compatible-660aa5018feb) on medium, you will get all the details on how to deploy it yourself, from scratch. You will also see how to setup everything to get external IPs on the LoadBalancer service.

Once you have it setuped, you can create a service and specify you want to use an IPv6 address this way using the `ipFamilies` field:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv6
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: The only part of this answer that actually answers the question is the "this tutorial" link.  "How do I install Kubernetes" is a substantial system-administration question in any case; please do not answer questions that are not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I removed the part about IPv4 scarcity, but I honestly think the rest is important context.